# WPF Countdown Timer Binding to different window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a control window with count down function. The count down value will be needed to show on a different window. For that, i created a class/view model as following:

```
public class RunningTime : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string runtime = "";

    public RunningTime()
    {
    }

    public string RunTime
    {
        get
        {
            return runtime;
        }
        set
        {
            if (runtime != value)
            {
                runtime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RunTime");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

After that, in the control window, I have a textblock and a button.
Textblock shows the count down time and button start the counting.

```
<TextBox Name="txtTime" IsReadOnly="True"
         Text="{Binding RunTime}"></TextBox>

<Button Name="btnStart" Content="START"
        Click="btnStart_Click"></Button>
```

At code behind, I have the following:

```
namespace Stadium
{
    public partial class Window_Control : Window
    {
            RunningTime _runtime = new RunningTime();
            private DispatcherTimer Timer;
            private int runtime = 65;
            public static string str_time = "";

            public Window_Control()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                base.DataContext = _runtime;
            }

            private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                    Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
                    Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
                    Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
                    Timer.Start();
            }

            public void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    if (runtime > 1)
                    {
                            runtime--;
                            string min = ((runtime / 60) < 10) ? "0" + (runtime / 60).ToString() : (runtime / 60).ToString();
                            string sec = ((runtime % 60) < 10) ? "0" + (runtime % 60).ToString() : (runtime % 60).ToString();
                            str_time = string.Format("{0}:{1}", min, sec);

                            _runtime.RunTime = str_time;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                            Timer.Stop();
                            MessageBox.Show("Time's Up");
                    }
            }
```

In second window which should display the count down timing in control window, I have a textblock also.

```
<TextBlock Name="txtGameTime"
           Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myDataSource}, Path=RunTime}"></TextBlock>
```

Too bad I am not able to display the time in second window.
Help needed on how to display the counting down time.

Thanks a lot.

UPDATE (Second Window XAML):

```
<Window x:Class="Stadium.Window_Game"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stadium">

<Window.Resources>
    <local:RunningTime x:Key="myDataSource"/>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock Name="txtGameTime"
           Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myDataSource}, Path=RunTime}"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: what is myDataSource? can you provide sample XAML for second window?

Comment: Hi, updated the xaml for second window

Comment: Please be more specific about "I am not able to display the time in second window". What do you mean by that, _exactly_? I.e. what happens with the code you have so far? How exactly is that different from what you want to happen?

Comment: `myDataSource` is not the same `RunningTime` object that's being used by the first window, so binding to it won't help. Why can't you just set the second window's `DataContext` to the same value as the first window's, and then bind the `TextBlock` the same way as in the first window?

Comment: Nothing display in the textblock in second window.
It just blank all the time while in control window, the time counting down perfectly.

Comment: hi Peter, tested the way you suggest. No luck.

Comment: The value for property RunTime on the instance myDataSource is not updating at all.  You need to add you timer logic in the RunningTime class. Start the time in the constructor or in separate method that is called when the class has been created.

Comment: Hi Azemia, could you please provide some pieces of code?
I can't really catch the ball. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Add your timer logic to the RunningTime class as outline below:

```
public class RunningTime: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string runtime = "";
    private DispatcherTimer timer;
    private int runtimeInt = 65;
    public static string str_time = "";

    public RunningTime()
    {
        LoadTimer();
    }

    public string RunTime
    {
        get
        {
            return runtime;
        }
        set
        {
            if (runtime != value)
            {
                runtime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RunTime");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    public void LoadTimer()
    {
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    public void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (runtimeInt > 1)
        {
            runtimeInt--;
            string min = ((runtimeInt / 60) < 10) ? "0" + (runtimeInt / 60).ToString() : (runtimeInt / 60).ToString();
            string sec = ((runtimeInt % 60) < 10) ? "0" + (runtimeInt % 60).ToString() : (runtimeInt % 60).ToString();
            str_time = string.Format("{0}:{1}", min, sec);

            this.RunTime = str_time;

        }
        else
        {
            timer.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Time's Up");
        }
    }
}
```

In your Window_Control class you will need only the following:

```
public partial class Window_Control : Window
{
        RunningTime _runtime = new RunningTime();
        public Window_Control()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            base.DataContext = _runtime;
        }
}
```

The xaml for the second windows will be:

```
<Window x:Class="Stadium.Window_Game"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stadium">

<Window.Resources>
    <local:RunningTime x:Key="myDataSource"/>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock Name="txtGameTime"
           Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myDataSource}, Path=RunTime}"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: SOrry, maybe I am not writing clear enough, i will need the count down timer to start counting down only after the user click on Start button in Window_Control. After that, the user might open second window. That time, the second window need to display the same count down time as in Window_Control. How to do this based on current code please? Thank you

Comment: You have to remove the LoadTimer() from RunTime() constructor and add <local:RunTime x:Key="myDataSource" to you App.xaml resources. Then use myDataSource instance in both window. In you button click event in your first window call _runTime.LoadTimer() to start the timer.

Comment: HI, tried as you suggested. The timer started counting yet nothing display in tetbox in  first window(Window_Control) as well as the second window.